# WPF ProgressBar Control Dispatch still blocking UI Thread

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls

I am using WPF trying to run a Thread in the background that updates a progress bar. I don't wan to block the UI thread so I am running the following code. However the UI still blocked. It seems so simple, what am I doing wrong?

```
       Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
        (ThreadStart) delegate(){                   
            for(double i = progressBar_ChangeProgress.Minimum;
                i < progressBar_ChangeProgress.Maximum;
                i++)
                {
                    for (int b = 0; b < 100000000; b++) { }
                    progressBar_ChangeProgress.Value = i;
                }
            EnableAllInputControls();
        }, DispatcherPriority.Background);
```

Answer (score 5):

Why not leverage the `BackgroundWorker` in this scenario...

```
        void Go()
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = new BackgroundWorker();
            worker.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
            worker.ProgressChanged += new ProgressChangedEventHandler(worker_ProgressChanged);
            worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(worker_DoWork);
            worker.RunWorkerAsync();
        }

        void worker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            progressBar_ChangeProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
        }

        void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            BackgroundWorker worker = sender as BackgroundWorker;
            for (int b = 0; b < 100; b++) 
            {
                Thread.Sleep(100);
                worker.ReportProgress(b);
            }
        }
```

**UPDATE:**

If you are wanting to use the `Dispatcher`; set the priority to `Normal` and perform the processing on the background thread then calling a method on the UI thread to provide the update.

```
        void Go()
        {
            ThreadStart start = delegate()
            {
                //this is taking place on the background thread
                for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
                {
                    //this is slowing things down; no real relevance
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                    //this will marshal us back to the UI thread
                    Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                                         new Action<int>(Update), i
                                         );
                }

            };

            new Thread(start).Start();
        }

        void Update(int value)
        {
            //this is taking place on the UI thread
            _progressBar.Value = value;
        }
```

Comment: I would, except I need to access multiple values of other UI controls in the segment where I have the for loop. Also, I read that Dispatcher was the MS preferred way in WPF of doing background tasks that need to updated the UI. I am not sure if that is true or not.

Comment: You've got things slightly confused. You want to do heavy, long-running work on a separate thread. BackgroundWorker is a good way to do this. The Dispatcher is just a way to get back to the UI thread for a short time and change a few things. Though if you use BackgroundWorker you don't need to worry about getting back to the UI thread: the ProgressChanged and RunWorkerCompleted events will fire on the UI thread, letting you update UI there.

Answer (score 2):

The `Dispatcher` is just a mechanism to run a bit of code on the UI thread at a later time. The priority you're passing in controls *when* it will get executed, not any type of thread priority. The contents of your delegate in this case are getting run on the UI thread. Using a `BackgroundWorker` as mentioned by Aaron would certainly help here.

Also I might point out that usually a progress bar shows how close a task is to completing. If you don't know how long something is going to take or have no way of measuring progress, you can use an Indeterminate progress bar. Only update the value if you have some meaningful information. (though you may have just provided this for demonstration purposes)

Comment: Was just writing that. To state the [msdn documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163328.aspx#S3): _"but since the UI thread is blocked for each piece of work routed through the Dispatcher, it is important to keep the work that the Dispatcher does small and quick."_ +1 For mentioning correct usage of progressbar. ;p

Answer (score 0):

Everything inside **BeginInvoke** is being run on the UI thread and so it will block.

What you need to do is run any time intensive code in your thread and then just update the UI inside the Invoke.

You want something more like this:

```
for (double i = progressBar_ChangeProgress.Minimum;
    i < progressBar_ChangeProgress.Maximum;
    i++)
{
  for (int b = 0; b < 100000000; b++) { }
  Dispatcher.Invoke((ThreadStart) delegate(){                   
    progressBar_ChangeProgress.Value = i;
  });
}
```